# Retrieving arn from another module

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to get the arn of the kms key for use in the S3 bucket `kms_master_key_id`, the code below is how I thought it might work. I can output the arn value to the root but am unsure how to access this in the S3 resource.

main.tf

```
  module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "./modules/S3"
}

  module "kms" {
  source = "./modules/kms"
}
```

outputs.tf

```
output "kms_arn" {
  value = module.kms.kms_arn
}
```

modules/kms/kms.tf

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cmk.json
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "key_alias" {
  name          = "alias/kms-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.key.id
}
```

modules/kms/_outputs.tf

```
output "kms_arn" {
  value = aws_kms_key.key.arn
}
```

modules/S3/main.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {

  bucket = "09432804238423098"
  acl    = "private"
  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
  force_destroy = true
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
   rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = ../aws_kms_key.key.arn
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

main.tf

```
  module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "./modules/S3"
  kms_master_key_id = module.kms.kms_arn
}

  module "kms" {
  source = "./modules/kms"
}
```

modules/kms/kms.tf

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cmk.json
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "key_alias" {
  name          = "alias/kms-key"
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.key.id
}
```

modules/kms/_outputs.tf

```
output "kms_arn" {
  value = aws_kms_key.key.arn
}
```

modules/S3/main.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {

  bucket = "09432804238423098"
  acl    = "private"
  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
  force_destroy = true
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = var.kms_master_key_id
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

modules/S3/variables.tf

```
variable "kms_master_key_id" {
  default = ""
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).